# failed to load static files express js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

new to node development.

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

my content gets as below

```
server.listen(1337);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});
```

I am trying to get static file as below

```
server.use("/", app.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

but it doesnt wonk getting errors.

How to get staTIC files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just read express docs

```
 var express = require('express'),
    app= express(),
      , server = require('http').createServer(app)
      , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

Answer (score 1):

the static function is a method on the express module.

So it should be:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```