# Express - issue serving client

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express setup with a rest server and a client. The rest part works fine. However, when the app loads the index.html, it fails to locate the (relatively pathed) static files referenced in index.html

The error on the console is:

```
   Warning: Unexpected block undefined on line undefined + of undefined. 
    This warning will be an error in v2.0.0
    GET /css/bootstrap.css 404 912.960 ms - 833
```

The app.js is:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var rest = require('./routes/rest');
var admin = require('./routes/admin');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use( express.static('/public'));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/rest', rest);
app.use('/rest/admin', admin);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems my app was missing this:

```
app.use( '/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

so I replaced:

```
app.use( express.static('/public'));
```

with that, and now it works. Thanks to @Konga raju for the answer here: [failed to load static files express js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968000/failed-to-load-static-files-express-js).
I didn't do @Fausts suggestion as this is in the file generated by express.